# Integral transform involving square root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am considering the following integral equation

$$\frac{1}{y} = \int_a^{\infty} g(x,y) x^{-1/2} \text{ d}x$$

where $g(x,y)$ is to-be-determined and $a$ is a positive constant (if it is instructive, it can be taken to be zero, but I am really interested in the $a > 0$ case.) I am wondering if there are any sources/literature that discuss this type of kernel?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose it _kind of_ looks like a [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform), though you would need to vet this with someone who is more knowledgeable in the area than myself.

Comment: Handbook of Integral Equations: Second Edition by Andrei D. Polyanin, Alexander V. Manzhirov